# fatal error: no input files

Tags: c, makefile, make

Olá, estou tentando rodar uma aplicação através de um Makefile, da forma

```
all: set.o main
    gcc main.o set.o -o main -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall -lm

set.o:
    gcc -c ./TAD_SET/set.c -o set.o 

main:
    gcc -c -I./TAD_SET -o main.o 

clean:
    rm *.o main

run:
    ./main
```

mas toda vez ele retorna um erro

```
gcc -c -I./TAD_SET -o main.o
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated
```

o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: No `main:`, não deveria ser  `gcc -c -I./TAD_SET/main.c -o main.o` ou `gcc -c -I./main.c -o main.o` (dependendo de onde estiver localizado)?

Comment: No caso, o `main` está na raiz, então deveria ser `gcc -c main.c -I./TAD_SET -o main.o` ?

Comment: Poderia usar _goals_ wildcard para fazer a compilação para arquivo objeto, e o `main` ser usado apenas para gerar o executável a partir dos objetos intermediários

Comment: Bom, pela resposta do @JeffersonQuesado isso tudo se resumi a um (ou mais) erro de digitação.

Answer (score 3):

O erro específico acontece porque o *goal* `main` executa a seguinte linha de comando:

```
gcc -c -I./TAD_SET -o main.o
```

Porém a flag `-I<dir>` tem como argumento obrigatório um caminho para um diretório onde será feito a busca por inclusão de arquivos `header` (ou `.h`, mas na real qualquer arquivo mencionado pela diretiva de pré-compilação `#include "file.smtgh"`). Mais contexto para isso, vide essa resposta e mais outras correlatas https://stackoverflow.com/a/558820/4438007

Com isso, não tem nenhuma opção na linha de comando que o gcc entenda como arquivo de input, logo a mensagem que não há input.

Me parece que você deseja ter `TAD_SET` como diretório para buscar inclusão sempre. Minha recomendação seria colocar ele sempre para toda transformação `.c => .o`, mas sem conhecer a fundo o projeto não posso fazer muito além de sugerir.

Outro ponto aqui que é importante: o *goal* de um Makefile deveria ser `.PHONY` ou então o arquivo gerado pelo comando. O *goal* `main` não gera um arquivo chamado `main`, mas sim um arquivo chamado `main.o`. O *goal* `all`, entretanto, é `.PHONY` com dignidade, porém ele gera um arquivo chamado `main`, e depende do *goal* `main` que gera o arquivo `main.o`.

O primeiro passo na minha opinião seria normalizar isso:

- `all` ser um *goal* `.PHONY` que dependa de `main`
- `main` dependa de `main.o` e `set.o`
- `main.o` dependa de `main.c` (e eventualmente algum arquivo de header)
- `set.o` dependa de `TAD_SET/set.c`

Também recomendo usar *goals* wildcard:

```
%.o : %.c
    gcc -ITAD_SET $< -c -o $@

%.o : TAD_SET/%.c
    gcc -ITAD_SET $< -c -o $@

main : main.o set.o
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

Makefile também tem um conjunto de regras padrão que são muito, mas muito bacanas. Talvez você não necessite nem declarar muitos objetivos e mais manipular as variáveis de compilação. Como, por exemplo, `CPPFLAGS`, que são as flags colocadas para pré-processamento do C. A flag `-I<dir>` é uma dessas flags que poderiam morar em `CPPFLAGS`.